# How can i make an array with strings located on parse.com?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, parse-platform

Hi guys i need to make a strings array in order to display it on a listView, those strings are saved on my parse.com data base.

this is the code that they give on parse.com to retrieve objects from parse.com

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // object will be your game score
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

This is the code of the fragment that contains the listView where i want the strings array to be displayed.

```
public class Grades extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.grades_fragment,container,false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.testArray, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//JUST FOR TESTING PURPOSES 

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"item" + position , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

i used an array created by me called testArray which should be replaced by the array that i want to make with the strings taken from my parse.com data base.

so my questions are 1) where should i locate the code that the parse.com suggests using ? 2) if i want that whenever a string is added to the database it also adds to the string array, what should i do?

Thanks very much for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can push the array as a string to your Parse storage, for example:

```
"jump run skip play" // representation of new String[]{"jump", "run", "skip", "play"}
```

Then you just have to use standard string methods to split the string at the spaces, or any character you choose to act as a separator.

Comment: Then use a JSON string.